# LinkedList with type alias

Tags: typescript, type-alias

I walk through [TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and came to the type aliases concept which I consider very attractive. Then I tried to run this code snippet:

```
type LinkedList<T> = T & { next: LinkedList<T> };

interface Person {
    name: string;
}    

var people: LinkedList<Person>;
var s = people.name;
var s = people.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.next.name;
```

what gives (TS v2.9.1): `error TS2454: Variable 'people' is used before being assigned.`

So I've initialized `people` as follows:

```
var people: LinkedList<Person> = 
     {name: "John", next: {name: "Jannet", next: {name: "Joanna", next: {name: "Adam", next: undefined}}}};
var s = people.name;
var s = people.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.next.name;
```

but now I'm getting TSError: 
`error TS2322: Type '{ name: string; next: { name: string; next: { name: string; next: { name: string; next: undefined...' is not assignable to type 'LinkedList<Person>'`.

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using string null checks (either with the `strict` or `strictNullChecks` options) then `undefined` is not assignable to `LinkedList<T>`.

The simplest option is to make the `next` field optional

```
type LinkedList<T> = T & { next?: LinkedList<T> };

interface Person {
    name: string;
}

var people: LinkedList<Person> =
    { name: "John", next: { name: "Jannet", next: { name: "Joanna", next: { name: "Adam", next: undefined } } } };
var s = people.name;
var s = people.next!.name;
var s = people.next!.next!.name;
var s = people.next!.next!.next!.name;
```

The problem is that now the next field is optional, and thus we must either check at each access that it is not null or use the not null assertion operator as I have done above (`!`)

**Edit**

If you want `people` to be typed exactly to the structure of the object literal but check that the object literal conforms to `LinkedList<Person>` you can use an extra function to create the object that will infer the type of the object literal but will raise an error if it does not conform `LinkedList<Person>`. The advantage is that we don't need any not null assertions (`!`) the big disadvantage in this case is that the length of the list becomes fixed, so not terribly useful, but an interesting side note :)

```
function createLinkedList<T extends LinkedList<Person>>(p: T) {
    return p;
}
var people = createLinkedList({ name: "John", next: { name: "Jannet", next: { name: "Joanna", next: { name: "Adam"  } } } });
var s = people.name;
var s = people.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.next.name;
```

Comment: Titian, yep I use strictNullChecks to see whether it helps or makes life more troublesome.

Comment: @MaciekLeks I expect both ;)

Answer (score 3):

@TitianCernicovaDragomir's answer is correct; usually you'd want some kind of base case so that your linked list can have a finite length.  But, in the unlikely case you want to make a type-safe thing that conforms to your original `LinkedList<Person>` definition, you could do something like this:

```
class Ouroboros {
  name = "AlphaAndOmega";
  next = this; // 
}
const people: LinkedList<Person> = new Ouroboros();
console.log(people.name); // "AlphaAndOmega"  
console.log(people.next.name); // "AlphaAndOmega"  
console.log(people.next.next.name); // "AlphaAndOmega"  
console.log(people.next.next.next.name); // "AlphaAndOmega"
```

In this case `people` is a [circular linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_linked_list) with only one unique `Person` element.